# Asp mvc roles system

Tags: model-view-controller, roles

I have method in  IdentityModels

```
   public bool InRole(string userId, string roleName)
    {
        var um = LocalUserManager;
        return um.IsInRole(userId, roleName);
    }
```

And when I call this method, I get exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: UserId not found.
```

UserId parameter has correct value. How I can resolve this problem?

edit:
add LocalRoleManger

```
    public RoleManager<IdentityRole> LocalRoleManager
    {
        get
        {
            return new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think we can help you without knowing what is inside ***LocalUserManager***.

Comment: I just added more code